# Missing some text when parsing page with Selenium-Webdriver and Ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Found mistyque issue with missing some parsing data. I try to collect all the texts under locator, hiden inside  tag. But when i collect it into Array i found that i always miss same words under same placed tags. If i try save text on higher DOM level, i loose same data with same logic (( And i can't realize whats happened and why ? ((

Someone can help me and explain that issue? My code is attached.

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox)
driver.manage.delete_all_cookies
driver.manage.window.resize_to 1280, 800
driver.navigate.to 'https://www.upwork.com/o/profiles/browse/?q=Ruby%20Selenium'
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)
wait.until { driver.find_element(:css, '.oDescription.m-md-top.m-0-bottom em').displayed? }
parsed_data = []
driver.find_elements(:css, '.oDescription.m-md-top.m-0-bottom em').map { |value| parsed_data << value.text }
puts parsed_data.inspect
driver.quit
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to get each description from the page, your css locator should be `p.oDescription.m-md-top.m-0-bottom`.

If you are not trying to get the descriptions, let me know and I can try to help you further.